# Select a specific cell in a csv file and return the column and row details in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the details mentioned below.

```
NAMES, Oil, Fat, Salt
Salad,  0.2, 0.1,  0.8
Bread,  0.1, 0.9,  0.1
```

For each row I want to find the minimum number of value value and return its row and column name separately. The output should be as follows.

```
E.g.,
['Salad', 'Fat']
[['Bread', 'Oil'], ['Bread', 'Salt']]
```

That is, if we consider `row 1` the lowest number is `0.1`. The row and column headings are `salad` and `fat`. For `row 2` the lowest number is `0.1`. The row and column headings are `Bread` and `oil` AND `bread` and `salt`.

I am interested in knowing if there is an easy way of doing it in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a lambda function and apply it to each row:

```
df.apply(lambda row: [[row.name, l] for l in row[row == row.min()].index], axis=1).tolist()
```

If `NAMES` is not the index, use:

```
df.set_index('NAMES').apply(lambda row: [[row.name, l] for l in row[row == row.min()].index], axis=1).tolist()
```

Assuming that you index is 'Names'.

Comment: This returns an numpy array, not a list. But you're right with the `set_index`.

Comment: Doesn't this return a list with 3 values even though the dataframe only have 2 rows? It can be difficult to associate the result with the rows in the dataframe afterwards (if needed). Especially when you have larger dataframes.

Comment: I'm not sure why OP anyway what's it this way, but yea.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
In [214]: df = df.set_index('NAMES')
```

then:

```
In [215]: df[df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)].stack().reset_index().drop(0,1).values.tolist()
Out[215]: [['Salad', 'Fat'], ['Bread', 'Oil'], ['Bread', 'Salt']]
```

or:

```
In [222]: df[df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)].stack().index.tolist()
Out[222]: [('Salad', 'Fat'), ('Bread', 'Oil'), ('Bread', 'Salt')]
```

Explanation:

```
In [216]: df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)
Out[216]:
         Oil    Fat   Salt
NAMES
Salad  False   True  False
Bread   True  False   True

In [217]: df[df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)].stack().reset_index()
Out[217]:
   NAMES level_1    0
0  Salad     Fat  0.1
1  Bread     Oil  0.1
2  Bread    Salt  0.1

In [218]: df[df.eq(df.min(1), axis=0)].stack().reset_index().drop(0,1)
Out[218]:
   NAMES level_1
0  Salad     Fat
1  Bread     Oil
2  Bread    Salt
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! However I want the 2nd row output in the same index of the dataframe as [['Bread', 'Oil'], ['Bread', 'Salt']].